# React Router - get History from Router reference

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-router-native

In `react-router` (esp. `react-router-native`) is it possible to get a reference to `History` object of the `Router` from the reference of the `Router`? (to be able to route from anywhere?)

Comment: react-router has a withRouter HOC component which exposes these props from the router context to your components: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your question is clear but I will put in my thoughts. You can access history object from any component which is called inside a Route. Also, if you want to access history object in a component which is not being called in a Route, just import withRouter from react-router-dom and then return your component wrapped like this withRouter(MyComponent).